# Wordpress adding theme option

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a theme, and the theme have social icons in the header, now i want a theme feature, where administrator can link their profile to social icons that I have on my theme. I researched on this, but am still clueless, till now I am just able to add theme option menu in Admin panel> appearance which have a text box for inserting social link. I am searching clue for grabbing the value of that textbox and add it in the anchor tag of social icon

Comment: You can create a custom plugin for your social icons, In which admin can provide their social links save these values to database and use it in your header.

Comment: you can use reduxframework plugin for developing admin option in your theme follow below link it will help you : https://wordpress.org/plugins/redux-framework/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use option tree plugin for it.

> https://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/

With help of this you can create your own theme option.
There is a two menus for it

> 1) option tree located at main menu of WordPress admin panel.
>       with help of option tree you can add settings for theme option.
>
> 2) theme option located at under appearance menu named theme option
>       with help of option tree you can add value of your setting fields.

And in code where ever you want to display theme option value you have to right small code given bellow.

```
<?php echo ot_get_option('slug'); ?>
```

Hope this info is helpful for you.

Comment: don't do anything else please go through option tree it is a easier way i found since last 2 year of my exp.

Answer (score 0):

Using Plugin. Try to this code.

```
<?php
   /**

Plugin Name: social icons
Description:this plugin is user for testing
Version: 1.0
Author: dev danidhariya
Author URI: http://www.fb.com/dev.danidhariya.09/

*/

define( 'INFO__PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'INFO__PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );

function myplugin_activate()
{
 global $wpdb;

$sql = "create table '".$wpdb->dbname."'.`wp_social`( 
   `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   `Link` varchar(1000) , 
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )";

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
dbDelta($sql);
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'add_menu_info');
function add_menu_info()
        {

                    add_menu_page('information', 'Test', 'manage_options', 'info', 'info_fun');
                }

function  info_fun()
    {
    ////add form to summit data in wp_social table in column Link to add ur link.

    }

?>
```

Using php to fetch Ur Link in theme.wp_social table in column Linl.